# Append string to text file in SAS

Tags: sas

I wanna append string to a text file at beginning and end of proc sql statment, I tried like below

```
libname DXZ 'libpath';
%macro processlogger(msg);
filename logfile '../Processlog/processlog.txt';
data _null_;
file logfile; 
put "%superq(message)";
run;
%mend;

%processlogger ('Begin');
proc sql;
    select * from DZ.NoofDaysin_Reje /* Mispelled name */
    run;

%processlogger('End');
```

I seems to messing up in macro variable, is there any other way I can do this, Thanks

Comment: What is messing up? Are you getting SAS errors? Wrong output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a data step to append to a text file then you need to add the `MOD` keyword to the `FILE` statement.

If you want to print the value of a macro variable that might have quotes and other strange characters in a data step then it is probably best to use `symget()` to retrieve the value into a datastep variable and print that.

Make sure to reference the macro variable that you created `msg` and not some other macro variable `message`.

If you don't want quotes to be included in the value of a macro variable then do not add them.

```
%macro processlogger(msg);
data _null_;
  file '../Processlog/processlog.txt' mod; 
  length message $32767 ;
  message=symget('msg');
  put message ;
run;
%mend;

%processlogger(Starting at %sysfunc(datetime(),datetime24.3));
%processlogger(Ending at %sysfunc(datetime(),datetime24.3));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [PRINTTO](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146809.htm) to redirect your log to a text file. And you have the option to either append to the original file or replace. Example [here](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n1oardywxmmut7n1pol0zkj5u1ok.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).

```
/*Redirect your log file*/
proc printto log='../Processlog/processlog.txt';
   run;
/* Your Code Here */
/* Reset log path to default */
proc printto;
run;
```